# Can dinosaurs be tamed while logged out?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

If you're very close to taming a dinosaur, but you have to leave the server for some reason, will the dinosaur continue to be tamed, assuming it has enough food and its torpor doesn't fall to 0 before hitting 100% tamed? My guess is yes, however, I don't have any source to back it up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but when I did that I didn't get Journal credit for the tame, so I had to tame a 2nd to get credit (which I would have done anyway, need male/female pairs).

Comment: I tamed a dino while too far away and also didn't receive credit for it. Additionally, my hard drive recently failed and I had to reinstall. All of my journal entries reset, as well as map exploration progress. It seems anything that persists between servers doesn't get saved on Valve's servers.

Comment: Maybe we can edit any file in the game's main directory who can change this informations? Like the journal entries and the map exploration progress... (check +1 :p)